# Jquery-Mobile: Changepage does not work if I specify pageid also I cannot pass data to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Iam using jquery-1.6.4.js ,jquery.mobile-1.0.1,and phonegap. I have not been able to navigate to another page using ChangePage using pageid(#target) of target page. If I user targetpage.html it works fine but target page still does able to receive data.

Following script is called from SourcePage.html

```js
               $('#btnaddEntry').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#hipage').jqmData('id',0);
                    $.mobile.changePage('#hipage');
               });
```

TargetPage.html

```html
            <body>
                <div data-role="page" id="hipage">
                    <div data-role="content">
                            Hi
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#hipage').live('pageshow' , function(event , ui){
                        var bookId = $('#hipage').jqmData('id');
                          if(bookId != null){
                           alert( bookId );
                          }
                          else{
                            alert( "No Data" );
                          }
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </body>
```

I tried all kinds of events and some other solutions that parse  window.location.href but nothing seems to work any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you specify page id the div with data-role='page' must be inside the same html file you working with. As you state in your question, to call another file you need to specify the .html name of the file, and it will take the first div with data-role='page' of that file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but then next question is how do u retrieve parameter value in target page. None of page lifecycle events are getting triggered or am I doing something wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally
http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2011/12/passing-data-between-pages-in-jquery-mobile/